# How to wait for a task to complete before continuing shell script

Tags: bash, shell, cron, scp

I have two shell scripts to write that will be executed nightly via cron schedule.

**On my production server:**

1. `mysqldump -ufoo -pbar --opt --routines db > ~/sqldump/{$todays_date}.sql`
2. `ln -s ~/sqldump/{$todays_date}.sql latest.sql`

**On my development server:**

1. `scp foo@domain.tld:~/sqldump/latest.sql ~/sqldump`
2. `mysql -ufoo -pbar db < latest.sql`

---

I have two questions:

1. In the production server job, how do i get `$todays_date` to fill in the date? e.g., "2010-07-21"
2. How do I make step two wait for step 1 to finish in each job?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get today's date, use `date +%F`:

```
command > ~/sqldump/$(date +%F).sql
```

To read more about the various options you can use with date's `+` formatting, check out the date man page.

As for waiting, I assume you mean you don't want to run the command on your dev server until the commands on your prod server are done.  The best idea would be to have the dev server start the command using ssh (i.e. `ssh user@host  "mysqldump ... > ... && ln -s ...`).

If you don't want to do that, the best I can think of is to use a temp file so that the dump file creation is atomic:

```
mysqldump ... > ~/sqldump/tmp$$ && mv ~/sqldump/tmp$$ ~/sqldump/$(date +%F).sql
```

Then if you have your dev server request's the dump from today's date, then you can loop until  the scp succeeds:

```
while ! scp foo@domain.tld:~/sqldump/$(date +%F).sql ~/sqldump; do
    # file not present yet, sleep 1 minute and try again
    sleep 60
done
mysql -ufoo -pbar db < latest.sql
```

Comment: +1, Thing to note, && will only run the following command if the first one has returned with an normal exit code. If you want the second to run, even though the first one might have returned a non-zero exit code use ; between commands instead.

Comment: Curiously, you've answered something useful but not exactly what the question states.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you use an "&" at the end of the command for step one, step two will automatically wait for it.

Comment: Don't you mean &&? & will just run it as a sub process.

Comment: No, I mean "&".  UNIX shells (almost) always run commands as a subprocess.  Without the "&" the shell will wait for the subprocess to complete before continuing.

So the clearer answer is: unless "mysqldump" backgrounds itself then step two of each cron job will wait for step one of each cron job.